# Elasticsearch cant sort by date when using multiple query_string [No mapping found for [[object Object]] in order to sort on]

Tags: elasticsearch

im getting some problems trying to sort a query when using multiple query_strings inside bool: { must [...]}.

When i remove the sort, the response is ok.
When i use only a unique query_string i can sort by `created_by`

There is some impossibility to make a multiple query_string and sort them?

Here is the query:

```
{
            index: "news",
            size: 100,
            from: 100,
            body: {
              query: {
                bool: {
                  must: [
                    {
                      query_string: {
                        query: "(new york) or (big apple)",
                        fields: ["title", "description"],
                      },
                    },
                    {
                      range: {
                        created_by: {
                          gte: "now-90d",
                          lte: "now",
                        },
                      },
                    },
                  ],
                },
              },
            },
            sort: [
              {
                created_by: {
                  order: "desc",
                  format: "strict_date_optional_time_nanos",
                  unmapped_type: "date",
                },
              },
              "_score",
            ],
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some mapping issue in your search query. The structure of the query should be like

```
{
  "query": {},
  "sort": {}
}
```

Modify your query as shown below -

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "(new york) or (big apple)",
            "fields": [
              "title",
              "description"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "created_by": {
              "gte": "now-90d",
              "lte": "now"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }                     // note the extra bracket here
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "created_by": {
        "order": "desc",
        "format": "strict_date_optional_time_nanos",
        "unmapped_type": "date"
      }
    },
    "_score"
  ]
}
```

Comment: @neus please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: To be honest, without bool: {must: [] }, the format with size outside of body was working, it maked me confuse a little

Comment: @neus that's strange because the `sort` part is always defined after the `query` part (as shown in the structure above)